# MIPS: Print Register Value To Console

Tags: javascript, debugging, mips

I'm trying to emulate the most basic form of javascript debugging in MIPS. What would be the equivalent of this (`$t0` equals a javascript variable in this example):

```
console.log($t0);
```

In other words, how would I print the content of some variable to the console in MIPS?

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: On Qtspim, I have ever used the instruction `syscall` to print intger value to console. Here is [link](http://www.tfinley.net/notes/cps104/mips.html).  Hope this help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`syscall` is the way to go. Also if you need a good interface to work with MIPS then I suggest this tool. It comes with some easy to use and strong debugging tools, which sound like might help:

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~larus/spim.html